# Do I still need tweaking after using gm/Id method if some of the MOSFETs are not in saturation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

gm/Id method links the design spec to gm, width, Id of each MOSFETs. There are some design examples that show how gm/Id is used in the circuit designs. They show the sizes of the MOSFETs and how it meets the design spec.

My questions:

1. Does gm/Id method guarantee the MOSFETs are in the saturation? I don't think so, but I need some confirmation since the design examples always show that the design meets the spec which means all the MOSFETs are in the saturation.
2. What should I adjust after using gm/Id method if some of the MOSFETs are not in the saturation?

assume that the circuits are the ones which require all the MOSFETs work in saturation (either weak or strong inversion).

edit2:

Let's say M6(and M5) and Mtail(showen as Iss) are not in saturation when I give a certain input VCM. I want to have a determined DC voltage on the output. let's say at mid point, half VDD. Before, I did it by doing so many trial and error as well as the [precomputed LUT method](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/systematic-design-of-analog-cmos-circuits/A07A705132E9DE52749F65EB63565CE0) and prefer not to that method again. I know that I need to find correct W and Vgs for each MOSFET, I also do not mind changing VCM, but do not know the efficient way to do that. I also want to make sure I understand what gm/Id method can do and cannot do, so I do not chase a ghost.

[image]

Comment: Specify what type of transistors you're asking about. Because for a BJT I **never** want it to operate in saturation when using the BJT as an amplifier. For MOSFETs I generally want these to be in saturation mode.

Comment: I edit the post to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does gm/Id method guarantee the transistors are in the saturation?

No, the **biasing** of the MOSFET determines if it is in saturation or not. Note that also a large signal can push a MOSFET (temporarily) out of saturation.

Realize that the \$gm\$ of a MOSFET is a **small signal parameter** and the value of that \$gm\$ depends on the mode of operation (linear / saturation), size of the MOSFET and biasing current. So the value of \$gm\$ **will change** when the MOSFET changes its mode of operation.

> What should I adjust after using gm/Id method if some of the MOSFETs
> are not in the saturation?

For designing amplifiers etc, you generally want your MOSFETs to operate in saturation mode. If a MOSFET is operating in linear mode then ask yourself if that is really needed. So in general if a MOSFET goes out of saturation then you need to **change the biasing** such that it will stay in saturation mode. By "change the biasing" I mean any action that changes the **operating point** of the MOSFET. If the drain current has to remain the same then changing W/L still changes the operating point.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it really help my understanding. One more little doubt: yes, in my case, I need Id to remain the same. if I change the W/L, doesn't it mean that I change gm/Id, which supposed to be the fixed because the value is derived from design spec? Also, if I have two out of 5 MOSFETs in the same biasing current path are not in saturation, I find it hard to find the correct solution (which value I need to tweak and how). This kinda negates what gm/Id method claims that the result are close to the design spec. Am I missing something here?

Comment: *if I change the W/L, doesn't it mean that I change gm/Id* Yes, changing the ratio W/L will mean that (at the same \$I_D\$) \$V_{GS}\$ will change. Look at the formula for \$gm\$, depending on what formula you use, W/L or \$V_{GS}\$ is in there so \$gm\$ will change. I would need to see the schematic to give you a better hint on what to do.

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: OK, M3 and M4 are **cascodes** for M1 and M2, you have to give \$V_{b1}\$ such a value that M1 and M2 are in saturation. In the same way M5 and M6 are the cascodes for M7 and M8. Note that this amplifier has a **current output** so you would normally terminate the output with a **voltage source**. That then also sets the DC voltage at the outputs and you can then choose it such that all cascodes are in saturation.

Comment: Often this amplifier is used (in exercises) with the output not terminated by a voltage source to get maximum voltage gain. Then the DC biasing voltage at the output is **undefined** as currents come from above and below. These currents are never **exactly** the same and even if they were, the difference goes into the output resistance which is very high. So this stage can only be used when there's a DC feedback loop to stabilize the DC voltage at the output.

Comment: Thank you. I actually kinda know what to do to have all of the MOSFETs in saturation i.e. adjusting the Vgs. The last time I did it, it took so many iterations. Is there any better method or adjusting Vgs through iterations is the only way? Can gm/id method solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You are probably talking about the "floating outputs" situation, so not applying DC voltages at the outputs like I suggested? With "floating outputs" it is **impossible** to make the circuit robust enough (unless you use DC feedback) so you will end up with a very sensitive circuit and in the "real world" small variations (that are always present) will push some transistors out of saturation. So your circuit will not be **robust**. Even a temperature change will disturb the delicate balance that you found to be the solution.

Comment: And no, gm/Id cannot solve this, without the fixed DC voltage at the outputs the DC biasing isn't predictable nor robust, without a robust biasing solution you cannot make a robust circuit whatever you do.